# Find type of generic parameter in method using reflection

Tags: java, android, methods, reflection

How Can i Find Foo and generic class for read method using reflection?

```
 public void contactUsAvail(List<Foo> list) {
       // method block
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as the parameter type `Foo` is erased at compile time. Type parameters are compiler hints only in Java and are not retained for execution.

But you could give your method a hint by passing in `Foo` as a method parameter:

```
public void <F extends Foo>contactUsAvail(Class<F> type, List<F> list) {
    if(SubclassOfFoo.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        //all elements in 'list' inherit from 'SubclassOfFoo'
    }
}
```